# ionic 3 change color on hover on svg and stay the same

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, svg, hover

I am writing a mobile app with Ionic 3 framework.

I want to change the color of an SVG when an user hover above a component with its finger. But the color needs to stay when he hover out of the component. It is like if he would be painting with his finger.

I tried CSS `hover` but it reverse back after leaving the component.
I tried the gestures event of ionic, but it seems that none of them help me.(https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures).
I tried Angular "mouseover" event. It works great on a browser, but not at all with finger on mobile or mobile simulator.

On click event, I use `[style]=myVariable` in the **.html** file. Where "myVariable" is `fill=#ffffff` for white, or `fill=#000000` for black in the **Typescript** file.

Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found THE solution.

This is pure web.

The idea is to use basic web event "touchstart" and "touchmove".
And use the event to get coordinates of the finger.

Then use function "document.elementFromPoint(x, y)" to get the element under the finger.

It should have been possible to directly access the "event.target" but, unfortunatly, the element returned is always the element which was under the finger during the "touchstart" event.

Then, I change the CSS dynamically.

We have to use "DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle()" to do so... This must not be done if you use an input from the user in the CSS. In my case, possible values are in an hard coded array.

So, read code above.

color-changing-svg.html

```
<svg id="colorChanginSVG" version="1.1" (touchstart)="handleMove($event) (touchmove)="handleMove($event)">
    <g transform="translate(-24.379463,-109.90178)">
    <path
        id="pixel"
        d="some-path"
        [style]=pixelColor />
      </g>
  </svg>
```

color-changing-svg.ts

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-color-changing-svg',
      templateUrl: 'color-changing-svg.html',
    })
    export class ColorChanginSvgPage {
          possibleColors: Array<string> = ["#ffffff", "#000000"]

          currentFingerColor="#0000ff";
          pixelColor:string="fill="+"#ff0000" 

          constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
          }

          handleMove(ev) {
            let currentElement = document.elementFromPoint(ev.touches[0].pageX, ev.touches[0].pageY);
            let id = currentElement.id

            if (id === "pixel"){
              this.pixelColor = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("fill:" + this.currentFingerColor)
            }
          }
    }
```